# Fix a child element position based on height of a div using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFopS.png). please check the image the date is actually out side the video player I uses jquery to get the height of the video player and uses its 90% to the top value to the date (position abolsute). But my solution is not that perfect how can I align the date always same position even the video player height gets changed on view port.  here are my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    // Your code in here
    let dateTop = function(){
            let videoPlayerheight = jQuery('.flowplayer').height()/100*80;
            jQuery('.entry-date').css('top',(videoPlayerheight));
           
                                     
    }; 
    dateTop();
    
    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        dateTop();
    });
    
    
    
    
});
```

I want to be the date always in same position based on the height of the video player (its not in the same div)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    // Your code in here
    let dateTop = function(){
            let videoPlayerheight = jQuery('.flowplayer').height()/100*80;
            jQuery('.entry-date').css('top',(videoPlayerheight));
           
                                     
    }; 
    dateTop();
    
    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        dateTop();
    });
    
    
    
    
});
```

Comment: Don't use jQuery, JavaScript for styling.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use pure CSS.

Give the video's parent class a position of relative.

Then the date absolute position it and set the bottom px value.

```css
.video1{
  height:200px;
  background:silver;
  position:relative;
}

.video2{
  height:300px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
}

.date{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:20px;
  right:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="video1">
  <div class="date">5 days</div>
</div>

<div class="video2">
  <div class="date">5 days</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick replay. The issue I faces is both the video player and the date are in different section and not able to give the video player div a fixed height(its a plugin loads the video inside iframe). Is there any way I can fix that position of the date using jQuery?